# ¿Cómo usar postgresql por primera vez?

Tags: postgresql, debian

El día de ayer formateé el computador con Debian y necesito seguir en mis proyectos pero no he podido usar postgresql de nuevo, en la terminal utilicé:

```
caro@caro-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
caro@caro-pc:~$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.0
```

Pero no me acuerdo qué pasos más siguen, dado que si hago lo siguiente:

```
caro@caro-pc:~$ sudo-i -u postgres
postgres@caro-pc:~$ psql -V
```

Me sale:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.0
```

Pero si hago, por ejemplo:

```
postgres@caro-pc:~$ psql -l
```

Me sale:

```
psql: no se pudo conectar con el servidor: No existe el fichero o el directorio
¿Está el servidor en ejecución localmente y aceptando conexiones en el socket de dominio Unix «/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432»?
```

Por favor, ¿me pueden ayudar?, ¿tengo que editar algún archivo de configuración?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bueno, en el caso de la opción `-V` es simplemente un flag para mostrar la versión, no se necesita conexión con el servidor:

```
postgres@caro-pc:~$ psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.0
```

El flag `-l` te muestra la lista de las bases de datos disponibles por lo que necesariamente requieres tener conexión con el servidor.

Lo que puedes hacer es asegurarte de que el servicio esté levantado:

```
$ ps aux | grep postgres
```

Si no obtienes resultados solo necesitarías levantar el servicio:

```
$ sudo service postgresql start
```

### Actualización

Por razones de seguridad, Postgres no permite las conexiones remotas. Si deseas habilitarlas tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

- En el archivo de configuración `pg_hba.conf`, agrega (red de ejemplo):

  ```
  host all all 10.10.29.0/24 trust
  ```
- En el archivo de configuración `postgresql.conf`, tienes que usar:

  ```
  listen_addresses='*'
  ```
- Reiniciar el servicio:

  ```
  $ sudo service postgresql restart
  ```

Comment: qué pena molestar césar , 2 preguntas:  
1. no tengo que editar el pg_hba.conf?
2. tengo que hacer sudo service postgresql start cada vez que inicie el pc? o de puede configurar para que inicie por defecto cada que inicie mi sesión en el pc?

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez si intentas conectarte remotamente tendrías que habilitar los accesos ya que por seguridad está deshabilitado. MIra mi actualización

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez cuando instalas el postgres debería haber creado el script para iniciar automáticamente, intenta reiniciar si no te funciona me comentas y lo vemos

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo utilizar la interfaz web: http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php

Comment: no uso php pero gracias

Comment: no es necesario que uses PHP, es un panel de administración web para PostgreSQL, de nada.